# How to parse a numeric value in a string?

Tags: teradata

Teradata question. I need to `select` those rows that have more than 4 consecutive digits for column `mycolumn`

I tried the following

```
SELECT  id, SUBSTR( mycolumn, ((POSITION( '3' IN CHAR2HEXINT(TRANSLATE( mycolumn USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN) ))/2)+1),  5) mycolumndigits
FROM mytable
WHERE TRIM(mycolumndigits+' ') LIKE '_ _ _ _ _ '
```

Sometimes I would get an untranslatable character exception, other time bad characted exception

Please help me to improve it

*(PS: I am not allowed to use Oracle functions (otranslate etc.). Also i cannot create stored procedures and functions. DBA won't give me access)*

Comment: How does your data actually look like? Are multiple groups of digits possible?

Comment: In the above code I try to get the substring of the first 5 characters starting on the position when i encounter the first digit. And then after trimming, i want to check whether this string has 5 characters (which is > 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the digits are always found at the end of the string this should work:
Check if the last five chars are digits.

```
cast(char2hexint((substring( mycolumn from (char_length(mycolumn) - 4)))) as char(10)) like '3_3_3_3_3_'
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried `select cast(char2hexint((substring( mycolumn from (char_length(mycolumn) - 4)))) as char(10)) like '3_3_3_3_3_' from mytable` but it did not work. Error: `expection something between ')' and 'like'`

Comment: You have to write it in the WHERE-condition. If you want an indicator column you might do CASE WHEN cast(char2hexint((substring( mycolumn from (char_length(mycolumn) - 4)))) as char(10)) like '3_3_3_3_3_' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: I tried the following  `SELECT id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE   CAST(CHAR2HEXINT((SUBSTRING( mycolumn FROM (CHAR_LENGTH(mycolumn) - 4)))) AS CHAR(10)) LIKE '3_3_3_3_3_'` and got 0 returned

Comment: What's the datatype of mycolumn? If it's a CHAR you might have to add TRIM: where cast(char2hexint((substring( trim(mycolumn) from (char_length(trim(mycolumn)) - 4)))) as CHAR(10)) like '3_3_3_3_3_'

Comment: You could use a simple "where char2hexint(mycolumn) like '%3_3_3_3_3_%'", but his might result in rare false positives for strings like 'cscsc'. To be 100% correct you need a function like oTRANSLATE or RegExp...